# setResult is not calling parent activity back

Tags: android, android-activity

There is something strange happening when trying to setResult back to parent activity
the onActivityResult method is not executing and my app terminates 
here is the parent

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Log.d("MyAPP","Access Calendar");
            //Getting the token back from authorization process
            accessToken = getIntent().getExtras().getString("token");
            // Setting up Calendar API Service
            setupCalendarConnection();
            startActivityForResult(intent.setClass(this, CalendarTasks.class),REQUEST_CAL_TASK);

    }
 @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            Log.d("MyAPP", "result arrived");

            if(requestCode==REQUEST_CAL_TASK){
                switch (resultCode){
                    case CREATE_EVENT:
                        getUserCalendars();
                        break;
                    case QUICKADD_EVENT:
                        getUserCalendars();
                        startActivityForResult(intent.setClass(this, CalendarQuickAddActivity.class),REQUEST_CAL_ACT);
                        break;
                    case VIEW_EVENTS:
                        getUserCalendars();   
                        break;
                    case CREATE_CALENDAR:
                        getUserCalendars();
                        break;
                    case EDIT_CALENDAR:
                        getUserCalendars(); 
                        break;
                }
            }

            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

Here is the child activity

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                listIndex=position;
                Log.d("MyAPP", ""+position);

                switch (listIndex){
                    case 0:
                        Log.d("MyAPP","case 0"+listIndex);
                        setResult(CREATE_EVENT);
                        finish();
                        break;
                    case 1:{

                        Log.d("MyAPP","case 1"+listIndex);
                        setResult(QUICKADD_EVENT);
                        finish();
                        break;
                    }
                    case 2:
                        Log.d("MyAPP","case 2"+listIndex);
                        setResult(VIEW_EVENTS);
                        finish();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Log.d("MyAPP","case 3"+listIndex);
                        setResult(CREATE_CALENDAR);
                        finish();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Log.d("MyAPP","case 4"+listIndex);
                        setResult(EDIT_CALENDAR);  
                        finish();
                        break;
                }

            }

        });
```

Am checking on Case 1 and Log cat prints out the right Log but doesn't print that Log in onActivityResut method which means it doesn't return back, and i don't know the reason behind this.
I moved the switch block to override finish() method and i got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The line,

```
startActivityForResult(intent.setClass(this, CalendarQuickAddActivity.class), REQUEST_CAL_ACT);
```

ensures that your result is returned to `CalendarQuickAddActivity`. Is this what you want?

Also, what exactly is the variable `intent`? Is it global? This is a little confusing... you might want to just create a new `Intent` with `new Intent(this, CalendarQuickAddActivity.class)` to make your code more readable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the problem occurs in the first activity call "startActivityForResult(intent.setClass(this, CalendarTasks.class),REQUEST_CAL_TASK);".
It should return the result to parent activity so that i can execute the line you mentioned where CalendarQuickAddActivity is the class i want to execute for a result from CalendarTasks class (The problem is am not even getting onActivityResult executed).
And yes intent is a global variable in parent activity where i use it in different activity calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ActivityGroup or TabGroupActivity then you need to overwrite handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data) instead of onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data).

Comment: Thank you, but no am not using either

Answer (score 0):

You need to call startActivityForResult then only it will go back

```
startActivityForResult(intent.setClass(this, CalendarQuickAddActivity.class), REQUEST_CAL_ACT);
```